# readfile returns additional digit

Tags: php, readfile

I am PHP beginner.  I am trying to readfile that is saved on a local machine. I have connection, I can read the file but PHP keeps providing with additional digit.

This is my code

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My first PHP page</h1>
        <?php
            echo readfile("/home/pi/test/hx711py/export.txt", "r");
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the other side the file is very simple it contains only number "10".
So the output should be  just number 10, but I keep getting 10 3.

This is the output on web interface:

[image]

This is the file I am trying to read:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

[`readfile()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) automatically echos the file's contents, so you don't need to use `echo`.

`readfile()` also returns an int and that's the 3 you are seeing.

Change your code to this.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>My first PHP page</h1>
<?php
readfile("/home/pi/test/hx711py/export.txt", "r");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for "readfile" function from PHP.net says :

readfile  
Returns the number of bytes read from the file. If an error occurs, FALSE is returned and unless the function was called as @readfile(), an error message is printed.

Source : http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php

---

If you want to read the contents of a file and get the result as a string use the file_get_contents function.

Documentation for "file_get_contents" function is available here :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php